# Unable to change voice in pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I checked out a similar question but it still couldn't solve my issue.
I wanted to put a female voice or just change the pitch of it. Few people suggested to change the voice id, further referring that **0** defined male voice while **1** defined female.

Although,
Trying out both voice ids, I get a regular male voice only,

Is it possible to chance the pitch of the voice for all pc's, as somebody referred it to as a **PC** audio problem, but in other language voice recognitions my PC works with different gender voices perfectly.

I also need to give gaps between each word, as in the regular voice, it speaks so fast, that the user has chances of not understanding a thing. If aware on how do the same, please tell me.

This is a code snippet on what I'm trying to work on:

```
import pyttsx3 #pip install pyttsx

engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice','voices[1].id')


def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I hope it works:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
    print(voice, voice.id)
    engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
    engine.say("Hello, world.")
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()
```

This should give you a list of voices.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain to us how and why your code solves the OP's problem as code itself is not always easy to read.

Comment: This answer does not address the goal of the question's author.